# Wifi P2P wpa_supplicant - failed to create p2p device interface

Tags: networking, wpa-supplicant, wifi-direct, wpa, p2p

I'm trying to configure wifi p2p connection with ubuntu, but I have some issues. 
 In particular I followed this [guide](http://riya80211.blogspot.de/2013/07/p2p-configuration-of-wpasupplicant-in.html) and this [one](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/p2p/howto)

Almost everything seems ok, but when I lunch the command:

```
sudo ./wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/p2p.conf -Dnl80211 -ddt
```

I get this error:

```
     1442591346.069280: nl80211: Set wlan0 operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
     1442591346.069563: netlink: Operstate: ifindex=4 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
     1442591346.069901: nl80211: Create interface iftype 10 (P2P_DEVICE)
     1442591347.591372: Failed to create interface p2p-dev-wlan0: -5 (Input/output error)
     1442591347.592233: nl80211: Failed to create a P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlan0
     1442591347.593031: P2P: Failed to create P2P Device interface
     1442591347.593754: P2P: Failed to enable P2P Device interface
     1442591347.594689: EAPOL: disable timer tick
     1442591347.595501: random: Got 20/20 bytes from /dev/random
```

After that, if I open anyway another shell and I type

```
sudo ./wpa_cli -i wlan0
```

the session seems to start correctly, but when I try to use p2p commands, they fail:

```
     wpa_cli v2.4
     Copyright (c) 2004-2015, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors
     This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
     See README for more details.
     Interactive mode
     > p2p_find
     FAIL
```

Someone can help me? I'm using a WANDBOARD quad device with Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.
I can't figure out why P2P interface cannot be created.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Does your wifi device support p2p-client/p2p-go interfaces? You can check under interfaces by doing "iw list"

```
     Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * AP
     * AP/VLAN
     * monitor
     * P2P-client
     * P2P-GO
     * P2P-device
```